# I am only able to grab the first group of text in between the tr need helping fixing my code

Tags: php

```
<?php
$tagname = "tr";    
$doc = file_get_contents("test.html"); 
$pattern = "/<$tagname>(.*?)<\/$tagname>/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $doc, $matches);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    echo ++$xx; //counts up every match
    echo " -- ";
    echo $match;
    echo "\n\r";
}
?>
```

This puts the text in between   into $match and prints it on the screen but only grabs the first occurrence and prints it 2 times on the screen it has about 20+ time the   appears.

How can I make it put them all on the screen each on a new line?

Comment: Don't parse html with regex: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/3933332

Comment: this would be the text in between tr tags

Comment: Can you show $match a bit not full. and what you expected as output?

Comment: Read preg_match doc more carefully especially the description of what $matches variable contains http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php . In your case you should use `preg_match_all()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: Ok I changed it to pre_match_all

Comment: var_export($matches[0]); I added to the foreach loop to see if I am getting anything and now I get double the data from the var and nothing from the echo statements

Comment: I would like to be able to use the echo statements to print each match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
foreach ($matches as $match) {
```

To:

```
foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
```